# CSS class map and Template Literal Type typescript

Tags: typescript

I have some states e.g. `’active’ | ’disabled’` and I want to create CSS class for them:
`component-name—-active` etc.

I want to store this in obj:

```
const CLASS_MAP: <how to type this> = {
  active: ’component-name—-active’,
  disabled: ’component-name—-disabled’
}
```

I tried

```
type State = ’active’ | ’disabled’;

Record<State, `component-name—-${State}`>
```

But this allow me to do unexpected combination as `active: component-name—-disabled`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TypeScript [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) to map over your `State` keys and define the dependant values.

```js
type State = `active` | `disabled`;
type StateMap = {[K in State]: `component-name—-${K}`};
```

This will give you the expected typechecking:

```js
// [✅]
const s1: StateMap = {
    active: "component-name—-active",
    disabled: "component-name—-disabled",
};

const s2: StateMap = {
    active: "component-name—-active",
    // ❌ error: Property 'disabled' is missing in type '{ active: "component-name—-active"; }' but required in type 'StateMap'
};

const s3: StateMap = {
    active: "component-name—-active",
    disabled: "component-name—-active",
    // ^^ ❌ error: Type '"component-name—-active"' is not assignable to type '"component-name—-disabled"'
};
```